# .bat - check for a string in file

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have a xml files filles with tabs and spaces. I am trying to search for a string in this file. File is something like below. I am trying to search for *`</ViewSettings>`* and this surrounded by tabs and spaces.

```
<ViewSettings>
  <Location>
  <X>0</X>
  <Y>0</Y>
  </Location>
</ViewSettings>
<WorkspaceName="FREE_UST_BETA_UA" PAth="\\mktxindfs\data_configuration\FREE_BETA"      IsAdmin="false" />
</Workspaces>
```

I have the code below

```
echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%X in (C:\add\WorkspaceXML\Workspaces.xml) do (
set "reference=</ViewSettings>"
for /f "delims=" %%T IN (%%X) do (  
        set output=%%T
        echo output:!output!
        if !output!==!reference! echo found reference.....
    )
)
```

It does not print "found reference"

Thanks

Comment: Do you absolutely need to do this task using batch files or windows command line tools?  Are you open to other tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered building your batch file off of `findstr` instead?  This command would tell you if the string was in the file by reporting the filename.

```
findstr /M /c:"</ViewSettings>" C:\add\WorkspaceXML\Workspaces.xml
```

**EDIT**

If you use `findstr /N /O ...` instead, you can get the line number and offset of the match(es), maybe that will be of more use to you.  The output in your case above would be

```
6:69:</ViewSettings>
```

**EDIT 2**

Proper offset added above thanks to dbenham.  Not sure if the offset is still of use to you, but to get both values in vars, try this:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N /O /c:"</ViewSettings>" C:\add\WorkspaceXML\Workspaces.xml') do echo %%a %%b
```

This just displays the vars for you of course, but you can set them as needed.

Comment: Hi Adam, Yes, I thought of this, but I was not sure if it tell me the exact location of this String in the file. I need to do some operations after this String in the file. Thanks.

Comment: @NewQueries - Updated above, hopefully that helps more.

Comment: This is great, so this will be my console output right? Is there a way I can get this value in a variable?(Mainly the line number)

Comment: @NewQueries - The offset is not as useful as you might think. It is the offset in bytes from the beginning of the file to the start of the matching line. It does _not_ show the offset of the matching string within the line.